# Complicated Boxed Frame Design by LaTeX

Tags: boxes, books

It has been long time not touching LaTeX and  I recently try to remember all things which I have forgotten. Instead of going over manuals, I look up some books which have some good design and try to produce some pages by LaTeX.

One book which I like is "A General Relativity Workbook" by Thomas A. Moore. I try to solve some problems on the it and type them by LaTeX. I asked Author he could send his LaTeX template, he told me he would like to but after having struggled  all summer in LaTeX, he gave up and designed  the book by Adobe InDesign and MathMagic.

So I would like to ask how to produce a boxed frame  like below. Especially I don't know how to make a frame around whole text including margin with pictures. Below is the page example (you could find more from http://pages.pomona.edu/~tmoore/grw/Resources/GRWBook.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Tried `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Your approach is flawed: looking at pictures of things you would like to do is not a good substitute for "going over manuals".  This is especially true since this site really relies on the questioner to post a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package. The resulting box admits page breaks.

[image]

A zoomed-in image for the box containing the figure:

[image]

Notice that the box spans the whole text width plus the margin notes area, but the text width is restricted to the standard `\textwidth`. This requires some special treatment, *via* overlays, depending on whether the box enlargement occurs on an even or an odd page, which is accomplished using the `check odd page`, `\strictpagecheck`, and `\ifoddpage` provided by the `changepage` package.

Material can be placed in the margin note area using `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package. Captions for figures, as the one shown in the example, can be provided using `\captionof` from `caption` (see example code).

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{caption}
\strictpagecheck
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\newlength\frameoverhang
\setlength\frameoverhang{\dimexpr2\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}

\definecolor{BoxGray}{RGB}{196,196,198}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=chapter]{Compbox}[1]{
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colframe=BoxGray,
  colback=white,
  title={BOX~\thetcbcounter\ #1},
  coltitle=black,
  fonttitle=\Large\sffamily\strut,
  width=\textwidth,
  check odd page=true,
  overlay unbroken={
  \ifoddpage
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.south east);
    \fill[BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.east|-title.south);
  \else
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      (frame.south east);
    \fill[BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      (frame.east|-title.south);
  \fi  
  },
  overlay first={
  \ifoddpage
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.south west); 
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.north east) --
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.south east);
    \fill[BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.east|-title.south);
  \else
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) -- 
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.south west); 
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north east) --
      (frame.south east);
    \fill[BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) 
        rectangle 
      (frame.east|-title.south);
  \fi  
  },
  overlay middle={
  \ifoddpage
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.south west);
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.north east) -- 
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.south east);
  \else
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) -- 
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.south west);
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north east) -- 
      (frame.south east);
  \fi  
  },
  overlay last={
  \ifoddpage
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.south west) --
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.south east) -- 
      ([xshift=\frameoverhang]frame.north east);
  \else
    \draw[line width=1mm,BoxGray]
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.north west) -- 
      ([xshift=-\frameoverhang]frame.south west) --
      (frame.south east) -- 
      (frame.north east);
  \fi  
  }
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\begin{Compbox}{The Metric Transformation Law}
\marginnote{
  \centering
  \tikz\fill[cyan] (0,0) rectangle ++(3,2);
  \captionof{figure}{this is a test casption for a figure in the marginal note area}
}%
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]
\end{Compbox}
\begin{Compbox}{The Metric Transformation Law}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{Compbox}
\begin{Compbox}{The Metric Transformation Law}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{Compbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Also, favorited the Q to learn the A later. Thanks.